# Operating system works after install and restarting, but not after a hard shutdown

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I received my computer back from the manufacturer after sending it there to repair a faulty RAM.

Now, I can install an operating system (I tried installing *Windows 10 Tech Preview* and *Ubuntu*), the system will run normally. If I restart it, it will still work.

However, if I let it shut down completely and then try to boot again, then it says:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

I am very sure that the hard drive is in the boot sequence.

In BIOS, in `Standard CMOS Features`, nothing is detected.
In Boot sequence, the disk is referred to as `ST1000DM003-1CH162`. It is a 1000 GB disk.
There is a seal on the tower so I can't verify that all cables are plugged in.

Booting from USB and CD always works.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like either the power supply unit or the drive is failing.  Test with a known-good PSU first, since it's easiest.

If the tower is sealed and you are afraid to break it, then you should go back to whomever sealed it and get them to perform the repair since you can't/won't open it to do any physical repairs without opening the chassis.

BTW: Your drive ([Seagate Barracuda ST1000DM003 1TB](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/docs/pdf/datasheet/disc/barracuda-ds1737-1-1111us.pdf)) is a traditional hard drive, not an SSD.

Comment: The repairer clearly failed to properly test the system before returning it -- this should go straight back under service warranty.